# Best approach to automate IE, MS-Office for setting verification in python

Tags: python, autoit, pywin32, pywinauto

What is the best approach  to automate  IE, MS-Office for setting verification in python. I want to access Tool Menu and other tool bars etc. not specific application operation. I have tried AutoIt and pywin32 but not able to get properties and method of objects.

Comment: You should be able to get to the object model of Office apps via COM, though I've never done it personally with Python. IronPython might be a useful route to investigate. This article also has some relevant info: https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=E7_2VJ7aDceToQSek4DYAQ&url=http://mil-oss.org/resources/mil-oss-wg4-automating-microsoft-office-with-python.pdf&ved=0CB8QFjAB&usg=AFQjCNHCzVdbht1ZHZj5ujsuykajnxu-lg&sig2=XbNkZXslS7-uMrmbPnjTHw

Answer (score 1):

For IE, I think IEC.py will work for you. Here is link.http://www.mayukhbose.com/python/IEC/

For MS-Office, I think Python-UNO bridge will work for you. Here is link.
http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html

Comment: Will the second link work for MS Office? It looks like it's for OpenOffice,  which is a different suite.